# How to increase accuracy of neural networks

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, feed-forward

I'm trying to build a simple neural network to classify product images to different labels (product types). i.e, given a new product image tell which product category type (books, toys, electronics etc.) it belongs to.

I have a couple of product images under each product number and each product number has a label (i.e., product type) in a excel sheet.

Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd
import glob2
import pickle

def image_to_feature_vector(image, size=(32,32)):
    return cv2.resize(image, size).flatten()

def read_data(xls = "/Desktop/num_to_product_type.xlsx"):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(xls)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    d = {}
    for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
        prod_type, prod_num = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=2)
        prod_type = unicode(prod_type).encode('UTF8')
        produ_num = unicode(prod_num).encode('UTF8')

        d[prod_num] = prod_type
    return d

def main():

    try:
        imagePaths=[]
        print("[INFO] describing images...")
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'/Desktop/data'):
            for filename in files:
                imagePaths.append(os.path.join(path, filename))

        files = glob2.glob('/Desktop/data/**/.DS_Store')
        for i in files:
            imagePaths.remove(i)  
    except:
        pass

    dd = read_data() 
    # initialize the data matrix and labels list
    data = []
    labels1 = []

    for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        #print(image.shape)
        subdir = imagePath.split('/')[-2]
        for k, v in dd.items():
            if k == subdir:
                label = v
                break

        features = image_to_feature_vector(image)
        data.append(features)
        labels1.append(label)


        # show an update every 1,000 images
        if i > 0 and i % 1000 == 0:
            print("[INFO] processed {}/{}".format(i, len(imagePaths)))
    print("String Labels")
    print(labels1)

    # encode the labels, converting them from strings to integers
    le = LabelEncoder()
    labels = le.fit_transform(labels1)
    print(labels) 

    d={}
    d[labels[0]] = labels1[0]

    for i in range(1,len(labels)-1):
        if labels[i-1] != labels[i] and labels[i] == labels[i+1]:
            d[labels[i]]  = labels1[i]

    data = np.array(data) / 255.0
    labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, 51)
    print("To_Categorical")
    print(labels) 

    print("[INFO] constructing training/testing split...")
    (trainData, testData, trainLabels, testLabels) = train_test_split(
        data, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(768, input_dim=3072, init="uniform",
        activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(384, init="uniform", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(51))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    print("[INFO] compiling model...")

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.125
              )
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd,
        metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.fit(trainData, trainLabels, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=750)


#     #Test the model
    #show the accuracy on the testing set
     print("[INFO] evaluating on testing set...")
     (loss, accuracy) = model.evaluate(testData, testLabels,
         batch_size=128, verbose=1)
     print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,
         accuracy * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

The neural network is a 3-2-3-51 feedforward neural network. Layer 0 contains 3 inputs. Layers 1 & 2 are hidden layers containing 2 & 3 nodes resp. Layer 3 is the output layer which has 51 nodes (i.e., for 51 product category type). However, with this I'm getting very low accuracy, only about 45-50%.

Is there something wrong that I'm doing? How do you increase the accuracy of the neural network? I read somewhere that it can be done by "`crossvalidation and hyperparameter tuning`" but how is it done? Sorry, I'm very new at neural network, just trying something new. Thanks.

Comment: Try using a net that's known to work well, such as Alexnet or Googlenet and retrain the last couple layers for your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating an image classifier in keras I would suggest trying a convolutional neural network as they tend to work much better for images. Also, normalizing between layers can help with accuracy during training which should help yield a better validation/test accuracy. (The same concept as normalizing data before training.)

For a keras convolutional layer simply call `model.add(Conv2D(params))` and to normalize between layers you can call `model.add(BatchNormalization())`

Convolutional neural networks are more advanced but better suited for images. The difference being that a convolutional is at a high level just a "mini" neural network scanning over patches of the image. This is important because for example you can have the ***EXACT*** same object in two images, but if they are in different places in that image a normal neural network would view that as two different objects vs the same object in different places in the images...

So this "mini" neural network that scans the image in patches (often referred to as the kernel size) is more inclined to pick up on similar ***features*** of objects. The object features are then trained into the network so even if the object is present in different areas of your images it can be more accurately recognized as the same thing. This is the key to why a convolutional neural network is better for working with images.

Here is a basic example in keras 2 with normalization based off of an NVIDIA model architecture...

```
        model = Sequential()
        # crop the images to get rid of irrelevant features if needed...
        model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((0, 0), (0,0)), input_shape=("your_input_shape tuple x,y,rgb_depth")))
        model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (x - 128) / 128)) # normalize all pixels to a mean of 0 +-1
        model.add(Conv2D(24, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', activation='elu')) # 1st convolution
        model.add(BatchNormalization()) # normalize between layers
        model.add(Conv2D(36, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', activation='elu')) # 2nd convolution
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv2D(48, (1,1), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', activation='elu')) # 3rd convolution
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        # model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='elu')) # 4th convolution
        # model.add(BatchNormalization())
        # model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='elu')) # 4th convolution
        # model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Flatten()) # flatten the dimensions
        model.add(Dense(100, activation='elu')) # 1st fully connected layer
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(51, activation= 'softmax')) # label output as probabilites
```

Lastly, hyperparameter tuning is just adjusting batch sizes, epochs, learning rates etc to achieve the best result. All you can do there is experiment and see what works best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try using Convolution Neural Network and see if the outcome improves.

Comment: I tried what you said but I get error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected cropping2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (39, 3072)

Comment: So keras cropping2d expects you to feed in an image, an image has an x, y, and rgb value....however, confusingly enough that error of 4 dimensions pertains to the batch size as well. So keras wants you to give it (batch_size, x, y, rgb) The rgb value should just be 3 if you are using color images.

Comment: I also wanted to say that you should be feeding the images in directly without flattening/reshaping them... so the array of shape (39, 3072) cant be right or that is an oddly shaped image.  If you print out the value of "trainData.shape" you should see a batch size, x, y, color_channel tuple. The last three values need to match the input shape parameter in Cropping2D. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. That's some really useful info! Ok, so I removed the inital flattening on doing trainData.shape I got (39,32,32,3) & I had supplied (32,32,3) to cropping2d as well. But that gives me some weird error: "AssertionError: There is a negative shape in the graph! " which I can't find anywhere on the internet as well.

Comment: The above error comes up on line - model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='elu')) # 4th convolution

Comment: So another reason convolutional neural networks are more advanced is because the convolutions reshape the image as they move through the network. What happens is you start with an image of (32, 32, 3), depending on the kernel size and the stride in each layer (stride is the overlapping scans of the image) the output of many convolutions will change the image size to be smaller with more depth, you will end up with (2, 2, 100). This represents an abstraction of the original image now and if you run another 5X5 kernal on that you will get a negative dimension error.

Comment: I edited the original code to cut the convolutions down as the model was setup for much larger images. Play around with the convolution dimensions and stride a bit to see what works...you will need to be less aggressive with the kernel size and stride for 32X32 images.

Comment: Thanks. That's very good explanation :) I do have very large number of images (about 35 gb), what do you suggest, while playing around to get the best CNN, do I used the entire dataset each time? Coz right now I was just trying it on about 50 images, which is nothing compared to the number of images I actually have in the dataset.

Comment: I would just set aside a few thousand images and experiment to get a feel for everything while you learn. Test the results and adjust, then if you want a more robust model try training on the full dataset. Just be prepared to wait a while if your not processing on a gpu...

Comment: Also what do you mean by "less aggressive" with the kernel size and stride for 32X32 images?

Comment: A smaller kernal size of 2x2 vs 5x5 or a stride of 1 vs 5. Your images are only 32x32 so you cant really use a large kernel/stride or you will run out of image quickly and get dimension errors. There is nothing stopping a convolution from iterating off of the edge of the image, thats when you throw dimension errors.

Answer (score 3):

## Hyper-parameter validation

Why did you choose a `3-2-3-2` ANN instead of a `3-6-2` or `3-4-4-4-4-2`?

Normally we don't know the exact topology (number of layers, number of neurons per layer, connections between neurons) that we need to reach an 80% accuracy or whatever makes us happy. This is where hyper-parameter training comes into play. With it, we tell our program to try with several different topologies until it finds one that is good enough for us.

How do you tell your program which topologies to try? we do it with another ANN or an Evolutionary Algorithm, which generate pseudo-random topologies, evaluates each one, and gives a score to each topology, then the topologies with higher scores are combined, and well, you know how it works.

Doing this will for sure help you increase your overall score (provided there is a good solution for your problem)

## Cross validation

How do you know how many iterations to do in your algorithm? what is your stop criteria?

There is a recurring problem with ANN called memorization. If you run your learning algorithm for 1 million iterations you will normally get a better score than if you run it for just 10 iterations, but it can be due to memorization of your training set: you ANN learn only to predict the outcome of those training sets, but will do poorly trying to predict data it has not seen before.

One way of solving that problem is cross-validation, which means you will split your data in 2 groups: `train` and `validation`. Then you train your ANN *only* with your `train` set for as many iterations you want, but in parallel, you will test your ANN with the `validation` set to know when to stop. If after 10 iterations your `train` accuracy keeps going up, but your `validation` accuracy keeps going down, then you can determine your ANN is memorizing, so you will stop your learning algorithm and choose the ANN as it was 10 iterations ago.

Of course, 10 is just an example, you can try with different values of even put this in your hyper-parameter training s you don't need to hardcode the value.

I recommend you take a look at the materials of this [course in Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) where they explain very clearly concepts like these.

(BTW: normally you split your input set in 3: `train`, `validate` and `test`. Where `test` is used to see how your ANN will behave with totally unseen data, you don't use that `test` set to take *any* decision in your training)

Comment: Glad it helps :)